# Tkinter display different frames

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

UPDATE : The problem was solved by removing the window.mainloop() in my second function.

I'm trying to make a game in Python 3.7 using tkinter.

The game begins with a menu (button-widgets in a frame). Clicking in the 'Play' button should open another menu using a different frame. This second menu should contain a 'back' button to return to the first menu.

Each menu is defined in a function. So to go from the *main menu* to the *play menu* I call the function playMenu(window) in the function used as command by the 'Play' button.

It looks like this :

```
def clickButtonPlay():
    menuFrame.grid_remove()
    playMenu(window)
    menuFrame.grid()
```

In the play menu, the function used as 'back button' command put an end to the function by destroying its frame and using return.

So the program should get back to the clickButtonPlay() function and show the frame of the main menu back, but instead I get a tkinter error :

_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "grid" command: application has been destroyed

But my frame menuFrame hasn't been destroyed, just un-grid!

Can anyone help me understand what's wrong with the code or find an easier way to do the same thing?

Thank you very much!

Here's a sample of how my program works:

mainMenu file :

```
import tkinter as tk
from PlayMenu import playMenu
window = tk.Tk()
window.grid()

def menu(window):
    def clickButtonPlay():
        menuFrame.grid_remove()
        playMenu(window)
        menuFrame.grid()
    menuFrame = tk.Frame(window)
    menuFrame.grid()
    background = tk.Label(menuFrame, image= backgroundImage)
    background.grid()
    playButton = tk.Button(menuFrame, image= playButtonImage[0], command= clickButtonPlay)
    playButton.place(relx= 0.5, rely= 0.15)
    window.mainloop()

menu(window)
```

playMenu file :

```
class MyError(Exception):
    pass

def _playMenu(window):
    def clickButtonBack():
        playMenuFrame.destroy()
        raise MyError

    playMenuFrame = tk.Frame(window)
    playMenuFrame.grid()
    background = tk.Label(playMenuFrame, image= backgroundImage)
    background.grid()
    backButton = tk.Button(playMenuFrame, image= backButtonImage[0], command= clickButtonBack)
    backButton.place(relx=0.375, rely=0.8)

    window.mainloop()

def playMenu(window):
    try:
        return _playMenu(window)
    except MyError:
        return
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Tkinter won't lie to you about a widget being destroyed, so we need to see a small example that replicates the behavior of your code.

Comment: @BryanOakley, I have edited my question, please tell me if you need more informations.

Comment: The problem is probably at least partially related to the fact you're calling `mainloop` more than once. You should call it exactly once.

Comment: You were right! I just deleted the mainloop in my playMenu function and it works fine! Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem (or at least *a* problem) is that you're calling `mainloop` more than once. Each time you call it, a *new* infinite loop is created. The new loop won't exit until the main window is destroyed. Once that happens, the previous loop will likely throw errors since the widgets it's managing no longer exist.